# HTML is displaying oddly when Flash is present

Tags: html, flash, mootools, tabs

The site I'm making uses a tabbed navigation and MooTools to fade the pages in and out. One of the pages has a Flash player embedded on it, and all of the others consist of pure HTML. The problem occurs on the HTML pages -- somehow the Flash player is causing the HTML pages to display oddly. Vertical borders and text will be jagged in the same locations of the top and bottom of the player. I don't have any code to show because it would be quite overwhelming to sift through, but has anyone run into a similar problem and know of a simple fix? Thank you!

Comment: Well is it possible that the container(div, whatever) for the flash changes the layout? I doubt flash itself is the culprit.

Comment: Also look it up in firefox with firebug or in chrome with the developer tool.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that this probably has to do with your wmode setting on the flash player.
Quote from http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=e5141

> Window Mode (wmode) - What's It For?
>
> There are three window modes. Windowless mode allows you to take advantage of the transparent movie, absolute positioning, and layering capabilities available in the browser. They are controlled with the wmode parameter in the object tag. The default mode is available by either choosing not to specify any wmode, or by using wmode="window". We'll look at Macromedia's explanation of the three modes and then we'll explore them a bit further individually.
>
> Window: Use the Window value to play a Flash Player movie in its own rectangular window on a web page. This is the default value for wmode and it works the way the classic Flash Player works. This normally provides the fastest animation performance.
>
> Opaque: By using the Opaque value you can use JavaScript to move or resize movies that don't need a transparent background. Opaque mode makes the movie hide everything behind it on the page. Additionally, opaque mode moves elements behind Flash movies (for example, with dynamic HTML) to prevent them from showing through.
>
> Transparent: Transparent mode allows the background of the HTML page, or the DHTML layer underneath the Flash movie or layer, to show through all the transparent portions of the movie. This allows you to overlap the movie with other elements of the HTML page. Animation performance might be slower when you use this value.

Adobe's property listing: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html

Answer (score 0):

you are using swfobject lib for adding the flash, arent you?

I had a different problem but maybe helps, with a jquery submenu been hidden by a flash movie, and I solved this with CSS  z-index property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everybody, for your answers. Flash is definitely the culprit here, since the problem only exists when the embedded Flash player is present. The player is actually created by Kyte, so it's not the standard players that are made through Flash/Dreamweaver. I tried changing the wmode parameter, which useful, but didn't work. And the z-index thing didn't work either. I'll keep trying it, though, because it seems that should work.